# evaluating a string as a partial bash command

Tags: string, bash, scripting

I'm writing a script in bash that reads this line from a file `next-version=2.0` and I want to extract the `2.0`. I can parse it as an array and split it on the `=`, but that feels like overkill. If I run `export $VERSION` which logically should become *`export next-version=2.0`* which I could then dereference with `$next-version`. Instead I get **`` bash: export: `next-version=2.0': not a valid identifier ``**

So I tried `VERSION="export $VERSION"` which evaluates to `export next-version=2.0` GREAT, so when I run `eval $VERSION` or `$VERSION` i get the same error. I think the *next-version=2.0* is somehow maintaining the fact that it's a string? I thought it might just be upset that it's reading from lowercase, but when I repeat the process with `NEXT-VERSION` same result.

Comment: It's not overkill, because the string in question is not a valid `bash` assignment statement. The only thing you *can* do is parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function or command name in `bash` can contain a `-`, but not a parameter name. This means `next-version=2.0` is not a valid assignment in `bash`, because the string before the `=` must be a valid name. The only thing you can do is parse it as you described, although there is no need for an array.

```
IFS== read -r name value <<< "$str"
```

or

```
value="${str#*=}"   # Strip the prefix up to and including the first =
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `-`

trying $
`` export STRING-SS=asd
bash: export: `STRING-SS=asd': not a valid identifier ``

change `next-version` to `NEXTVERSION`, `NEXT_VERSION`, `next_version` or `nextversion`.